# Pass Path Parameters to a Data Connector API (/users/{user_id})using a Watcher

Tags: http-get, processmaker, http-parameters, processmaker-api

Using a Watcher to trigger a ProcessMaker API call to /users/{user_id} via a Data Connector.
**This is the Data Connector:**
[Data Connector Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd3cJ.png)

Key is user_id. Path is api/1.0/users/{{user_id}}.

**This is the Watcher:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtSoh.png)

Outbound Configuration:
type: PARAM. key: user_id.

**Problem:** The Watcher is passing the value as a path parameter *and* generating a query parameter string, which results in no data.

**My question:** Can a Data Connector Watcher not use path parameters, or I am I missing something where I can tell the watcher to just add the passed parameter as part of the path instead of generating a query string?

**Example:** When I pass "2" as a parameter value via request data, the watcher generates the path api/1.0/users/2?user_id=2, which results in no data.

Clearly, my argument is making it in, but I assume the Watcher can only generate query parameters, because there is no control to indicate how the Watcher is going to interpret the parameter. Also the test call in Data Connector editor does work, which leads me to believe this is a Watcher problem.